# Is it possible to change name of the system table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to change name of the system table in my database is it possible? Probably I shouldn't change it but I'm curious.

When I execute `sp_rename` I get the following error:

> Msg 15001, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_rename, Line 404
>   Object 'cdc.[dbo_CdcTest_CT]' does not exist or is not a valid object for this operation.

Edit:
I want to change name of tables created by Change Data Capture because I want to disable CDC mechanism for table and still have data - I know that I can create additional table and move there data from CDC table but it's easier to change name of the CDC and then disable cdc for specified table.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? I guess you will have serious  problems __if you ever succeed__, as the SQL server internally queries these tables and relies on their proper names. Please, add more details to your question rather than comment back, as it is not confirming to the established format in SO. Thanks.

Comment: If you just want to refer to it by a different name, you could use a [synonym](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx)

Comment: It seems to be there is a problem with your registered SP, So try to create it with a different name with small change. It 'll done the job..

Comment: And FYI `sp_rename` can only change the name of a user-created object in the current database.

Comment: @Ivaylo Slavov I want to change name of tables created by Change Data Capture. Why? I want to disable CDC mechanism for table and still have data - I know that I can create additional table and move there data from CDC table but it's easier to change name of the CDC and then disable cdc for specified table.

Comment: @Adam, this seems a reasonable concern. I recommend you to add this to the body of your question, as comments are harder to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No** you cannot change the name of the system tables. However you can refer it with a different name.

You can use [synonyms](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544.aspx) for that:

```
CREATE SYNONYM [ schema_name_1. ] synonym_name FOR <object>

<object> :: =
{
    [ server_name.[ database_name ] . [ schema_name_2 ].| database_name . [ schema_name_2 ].| schema_name_2. ] object_name
}
```

Also to mention that [sp_rename](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx)

> ## Changes the name of a user-created object in the current database.
>
>
>   This object can be a table, index, column, alias data type, or
>   Microsoft .NET Framework common language runtime